# Convert time shown as hours and minutes in three to four digits within a dataframe to minutes

Tags: r, dataframe, time

I have a dataframe with a column named "time" (which has an integer class). The time comes in three or four digits e.g. 514, which means 5:14 am, or 1914, which means 19:14. I need to create a new column "time_2" which will have the time of the "time" column but only showing minutes. For example, if row 1 has the value "514" for the "time" column, that needs to go to a new column named "time_2" with a first value of "314" minutes.

I tried to "remove" the first digit and then multiply it by 60 and the following two digits sum it to the latter. However, I was not able to accomplish it, and the fact that there is also data with four digits made me stop and search for some help. I just don't know how to do it. I'd truly appreciate some help.

(Language: R)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your times are never outside of the 00:00-23:59 window, you can use `as.difftime` from base R:

```
x <- c(514,1914)

as.difftime(sprintf("%04d", x), format="%H%M", units="mins")
#Time differences in mins
#[1]  314 1154
```

Times outside this range can be dealt with using a little arithmetic:

```
as.numeric(
  as.difftime(x %/% 100 + (x %% 100)/60, units="hours"),
  units="mins"
)
#[1]  314 1154
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the numbers to `timestamp` and extract hours and minutes using `substr`

```
library("lubridate")

InPut
time <- c(521,1914)
time <- substr(as.POSIXct(sprintf("%04.0f", time), format='%H%M'), 12, 16) # Extracting hours and minutes using substr
time <- as.POSIXct(x = time, format = "%H:%M", tz = "UTC")
hour(time) * 60 + minute(time)

OutPut:
[1]  321 1154
```

Answer (score 0):

in more simpler manner:

```
library(lubridate)
time <- c(521,1914)
60 *hour(parse_date_time(time, "HM"))+ minute(parse_date_time(time, "HM"))
```